# Do all "good" endings end with the destruction of the Mass Relays?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I've gone through my first ending with ~3800 EMS.  With my handy save point for just before the assault on Earth, I plan to up my readiness and go at it again.  The one question I have is

> do all "good" (EMS > 2800) or every ending involve the Mass Relays blowing up?

Comment: [You can see for yourself!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPelM2hwhJA)

Comment: That said, I have removed speculative questions from this since those aren't explicable at this juncture. Carry on!

Comment: @RavenDreamer post that as part of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Control ending:

> The destruction of the relays is not as explicit. 
>  I rationalize the explosion of the mass relays not destroying the solar system since all of the energy is focused further out into the relay network.

As for what effect the ending has on the future of the franchise?  The Bioware writers are a talented lot, and I'm sure they'll figure something out if they want to.

Comment: Thanks for the spoiler fix.  There's something goofy about iPad exclamation points.